# How do i use C++ with Flex?

Tags: c++, flex-lexer

How can i outsource performance critical stuff to C++.
Is there any example ?

Comment: As you are asking about Bison, I suspect you are also asking about the flex lexer generator. This is not what the SO "flex" tag is about. Please retag, and please add some detail to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're talking about Flex on AIR platform (basically out of browser application), there's a way to interact with native code on the same machine.
You may want to check this out (official doc from Adobe) : http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/ajax/quickstart/interacting_with_native_process_print.html

If you're talking about flex in the browser, then I would agree with Dmitry, you can use many different things:
 - Web Services
 - HTTP Request/Response
 - RPC calls
 - Or even make your own real-time socket (in some cases can be the most performant way to do this)
Now, that would require a C++ Server, listening to those calls, doing the stuff and then replying. => Meaning you need networking.

Answer (score 0):

Now this is somewhat confusing based on tags that you chose. flex and **bison** are used to create compilers, and related tools.

If you are using Adobe flex then you would generally get your data from a webservice. There are toolkits that can help you create these webservices with C++ like gSOAP http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~engelen/soap.html.